# Como alinhar lado a lado a tag li dentro do laço for em html flask jinja2?

Tags: html, python, flask

##### Como faço para alinhar lado a lado a tag `li` dentro do laço `for` em [flask](/questions/tagged/flask)

```html
{% for g in groups %}
<div class='circle'>
   <ul class="circle-list">
      <li class="group">
         <a href="/layers">
            <svg id="{{g.id}}" width="250" height="250" onclick="funcaoBotao({{ g.id }});">
               <circle cx="95" cy="95" r="85" />
               <text x="38%" y="40%" text-anchor="middle" fill="white" font-size="16px" font-family="Arial" dy=".3em">{{ g.name }}</text>
            </svg>
         </a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, não esqueça de fechar as tags `<ul>` e `<li>` que estão abertas mas não fechadas.

Depois, para realizar isso você precisa usar css. Crie um arquivo css que referencie esse código html. Nesse arquivo css escreva:

```
ul {
  display: flex;
}
```

Creio que assim funcionará.

Comment: Certo funcionou